# setting selected option on select in angular ngoptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanted to set selected option in my dropdown list.

I have two ways of passing data into selects ng-model

```
first: $scope.selectedTeam = $scope.teams[31];

second: $scope.selectedTeam = selectedTeamSrvs.getTeam()
```

my html select looks like this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedTeam" 
    ng-options="team as team.name for team in teams | orderBy:'ID'">
</select>
```

and `JSON.stringify($scope.teams[31]) === JSON.stringify(selectedTeamSrvs.getTeam())` gives true.
Then why only first option sets selected option correctly?

Comment: that what you need to do... $scope.selectedTeam =  JSON.stringify(selectedTeamSrvs.getTeam());

Comment: Sorry bad paste, stand corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default, ngModel compares by reference, not value.This is important when binding to an array of objects

Second option is not setting correctly because selectedTeamSrvs.getTeam() returns a different instance of team, even though they are equal when stringified.